# How to remove spackle

Tags: spackling-paste

How to  remove dried spackle from between the edge of a cabinet and the wall? I’ve tried using a screwdriver and a spackle knife but the spackle is very hard.

Comment: can you include an image?

Comment: Try using a single edge razor blade. Don't just use the tip or you'll scratch the cabinet, use the entire sharp edge and lightly push it across the surface. You can add a little water and it will make it easier. Use a blade similar to the one below, you want the rigid edge so the blade doesn't bend and scratch the cabinet.

Comment: i know that steam cleaners will take it right off with no scraping or scratches.

Comment: If it is "very hard", it ain't spackle...

Answer (score 2):

Try using a single edge razor blade. Don't just use the tip or you'll scratch the cabinet, use the entire sharp edge and lightly push it across the surface. You can add a little water and it will make it easier. Use a blade similar to the one below, you want the rigid edge so the blade doesn't bend and scratch the cabinet.

[image]